# How to freeze python app with GnuPG (gpg) executable and dependencies (PyInstaller)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, gnupg, pgp

How do I include `gpg` (and all its dependencies) when I build my app with [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

I'm releasing my python app as standalone executables for Linux, Windows, and MacOS using `PyInstaller`. I need to use `gpg`, so I'm using the [`python-gnupg`](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/) module -- which basically just shells out to the locally-installed `gpg` binary on the system.

Because my app is designed to be a "portable" executable (I use `PyInstaller` to ship it with the `python` interpreter and all the other dependencies), I want to include `gpg` with my releases so the user doesn't have to install it on their machine.

How can I add the `gpg` binary and all its dependencies for the `python-gnupg` module using `PyInstaller` targeting Linux, Windows, and MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package GnuPG with your PyInstaller-built app by adding the `gpg` binary and all its dependencies [using the `Analysis.datas` key](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).

## Windows

On windows, I got this to work with trial and error. First I just searched the entire system for the `gpg.exe` binary. In powershell:

```
> Get-Command gpg
0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe
>
```

Then I added it to my PyInstaller `.spec` file by changing this section

```
a = Analysis(['..\\src\\main.py'],
             pathex=['.\\'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'libusb1'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Into this

```
a = Analysis(['..\\src\\main.py'],
             pathex=['.\\'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=
              [
               ('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\gpg.exe', '.'),              ],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'libusb1'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

After the above change, my app would popup a warning error, such as:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because msys-bz2-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

One-by-one, I kept finding (using `Get-Command` in powershell as shown above) & adding the `.dll` files it complained about until my `datas` in the spec file above had the following contents, which worked:

```
             datas=
              [
               ( '..\\KEYS', '.' ),
               ('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\gpg.exe', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-bz2-1.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-assuan-0.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-gcrypt-20.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-gpg-error-0.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-2.0.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-readline8.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-z.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-sqlite3-0.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-iconv-2.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-intl-8.dll', '.'),
               ('C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\msys-ncursesw6.dll', '.'),
              ],
```

You can see my full build script and `.spec` file here:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/a35ff11985a19d19d23eb5e219b7ce26d5090c27/build/windows/buildExe.ps1#L136-L190

## MacOS

In MacOS, I found that I didn't have to add any dependencies--only the executable.

```
             datas=[ ('/usr/local/bin/gpg', '.') ],
```

You can see my full build script and `.spec` file here:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/a35ff11985a19d19d23eb5e219b7ce26d5090c27/build/mac/buildDmg.sh#L141-L183

## Linux

I actually didn't build a release for Linux using PyInstaller as I'm using AppImage instead.

To see my full build script for Linux, see:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/a35ff11985a19d19d23eb5e219b7ce26d5090c27/build/linux/buildAppImage.sh#L114-L115